# Add separation on ng-repeat values angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<span ng-repeat="sport in profile.sports track by $index">
      {{ (profile.type == 2) ? ($index >= 0) ? sports[sport.sport_id] + ", " : sports[sport.sport_id] : '' }}
</span>
```

I want each element to be separate by `,` if there is at least 1 item.

Expected result in `sports[sport.sport_id]`:

```
cricket, football, hockey
cricket, hockey
cricket
cricket, soccer
```

Currently I'm getting all these without commas, please suggest, thanks.

Comment: Can you show how the `$scope.profile` looks like?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<span ng-repeat="sport in profile.sports track by $index">
     {{ modifiedSport(sport, $index) }}
</span>
```

and add this to your controller

```
$scope.modifiedSport = function(sport, idx){
    ($scope.profile.type == 2) ? (idx >= 0) ? $scope.sports[sport.sport_id] + ", " : $scope.sports[sport.sport_id] : ''
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript `join` with comma separated

*Example*

```
<span ng-repeat="sport in [{value: ['a']}, {value: ['b','c']}]">
      <pre>{{sport.value.join(', ')}}</pre>
</span>
```

*Ouput:*

```
a
b, c
```

Comment: In my case what will be the exact code 

as i Use custom filter but it does not work

Comment: filter('joinBy', function () {
        return function (input,delimiter) {
            return (input || []).join(delimiter || ',');
  }
});

Comment: {{sports[sport.sport_id] | joinBy:','}}

Comment: Error: (intermediate value).join is not a function